# Going to edit page gives text with no template

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

I saw a question on Skeptics (I don't have an account there) with bad grammar. I didn't see the edit button, so I went to `/posts/postID/edit`. However, I got this screen:

[image]

Just a blank page with plain text. Although this gets the point across, the page should share the same template as the rest of the site.

Comment: Really, you shouldn't be booted off to a separate page at all. You should just see one of the little pop-up dialogs like you see for everything else.